# Find $\sqrt{2}\sin x=-1$ and $\sin x = -\frac{1}{2} \land x \in \left]-\frac{5\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{2}\right]$

Tags: trigonometry

I have two questions:

**1)**

To solve $\sqrt{2}\sin x=-1$ I did:

$$\sqrt{2}\sin x=-1 \Leftrightarrow \sin x = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \Leftrightarrow x = \arcsin\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + 2\pi k \lor x = \pi -\arcsin\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt 2}\right) + 2\pi k $$

My book says the solution is:

$$x = \frac{5\pi} 4 +k2\pi \lor x = \frac{7\pi} 4 + k2\pi$$

What did I do wrong?

**2)**

To solve $\sin x = -\frac{1}{2} \land x \in \left]-\frac{5\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{2} \right]$ I did:

$$x = \arcsin\left(\frac{-1} 2 \right)+2\pi k$$

But my book says the solution is $x \in \{-\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{7\pi}{6},\frac{11\pi}{6}\}$

What did I do wrong?

Also, is there any trick for converting between a decimal number to a fraction with $\pi$ like in my book's answers?

Comment: arcsin(-1/sqrt(2)) = 5*pi/4 or 7*pi/4  and arcsin(-1/2) = 7*pi/6 or 11*pi/6 and     -pi/6 = 2*pi - pi/6 = 11*pi/6  so your answer is correct you just have to convert to angles instead of leaving in arcsin

Comment: @ManikSin My answer is correct for which one? Did I get both right?

Answer (score 1):

$\sin^{-1} (-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}) = \arcsin(-\frac{1}{\sqrt2})=-π/4$

$-\frac{π}{4}+\frac{8π}{4}=\frac{7π}{4}$

You can freely add and subtract  $\frac{8π}{4}(=2π)$ which is the period of sine.

$π-(-\frac{π}{4})=\frac{5π}{4}$

And it's the same for your other problem. Very simple. You have to account for the restriction. The problem says $x$ should be between $-\frac{5π}{6}$ and $\frac{5π}{2}$. So no $2kπ$ there! (k is any integer; it can be a million)

Sometimes you will need to combine different solutions and more intricate operations might be required, such as going from $(2k+1)π$ and $2nπ$ to a combined answer of $mπ$.

By the way, for tangents you can freely add and subtract $π$ as a period of tangent in trig equations like these.

PS: Don't know how to write the inverse of sine - gotta learn this LaTex a lot more $sin^-1$  :((

Comment: Imago, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For #1: $\sqrt 2 sin x = -1$ implies that $\sin x$ = $-\frac {\sqrt 2} {2}$, meaning the angles lie in the 3rd and 4th quadrants.  The principal value of $\sin x$ is $-\frac {\pi} {4}$; thus $\frac {\ 5 \pi} {4}$ and $\frac {\ 7 \pi} {4}$ are correct in the unit circle $0 < x < 2 \pi$.  Of course, we can add $2 \pi k$ to both to get all values.

For #2: We are looking for angles between -$\frac {5 \pi}{6}$ and $\frac {5 \pi}{2}$; -$\frac {5 \pi}{6}$ is really equal to $\frac {7 \pi}{6}$; we are thus looking again at the 3rd and 4th quadrants since $\sin x$ is negative there.  In this case, x = -$\frac {\pi}{6}$ is the principal value; the angles are thus -$\frac {\pi}{6}$, $\frac {7 \pi}{6}$, and $\frac {11 \pi}{6}$ within that range.